# Nutritional supplements for the brain

Tags: supplements

There are a million things to eat/drink when working out.  When I go for a long bike ride, I've found that Gatorade and occasionally those shot bloks keep me fueled very well.  Are there similar products for getting a boost of energy and mental focus while not being physically active?

I work in an office all day, and on occasion end up working 12-15 hours a day for a week or so.  This gets mentally exhausting after a couple days.  Is it advisable to use the same supplements while not doing physical activity?

Comment: It isn't as much the supplements as it is the insulin spike which gives you focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water, fish, eggs, Antioxidant-Rich Fruits and Vegetables, green tea, and complex carbs are suppose to be good for the brain providing: omega-3, mental alertness as well as build-up of plaque in brains from amyloid deposits, and among others http://unfrazzledcare.com/10-best-foods-supplements-for-brain-health/